# JavaScript list saving question

Tags: javascript

I have this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y8Uju/5/

I am trying to save the numbers, because, when I submit, the list of numbers gets erased. I am a little new to JavaScript so am not quite familiar to what is available. In PHP I would use sessions to save the list, but what can I do in JavaScript to do this?

Here is the JavaScript code:

```
function bindName() {
    var inputNames = document.getElementById("names").getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (i = 0; i < inputNames.length; i++) {
        inputNames[i].onkeydown = function() {
            if (this.value == "") {
                setTimeout(deletename(this), 1000);
            }
        }
    }
}

document.getElementById("addName").onclick = function() {
    var num1 = document.getElementById("name");
    var myRegEx = /^[0-9]{10}$/;
    var itemsToTest = num1.value;

    if (myRegEx.test(itemsToTest)) {
        var form1 = document.getElementById("names");

        var nameOfnames = form1.getElementsByClassName("inputNames").length;

        var newGuy1 = document.createElement("input");

        newGuy1.setAttribute("class", "inputNames");
        newGuy1.setAttribute("id", nameOfnames);
        newGuy1.setAttribute("type", "text");
        newGuy1.setAttribute("value", num1.value);

        form1.appendChild(newGuy1);
        num1.value = "";
        bindName();
    }
    else {
        alert('error');
    }
};

function deletename(name) {
    if (name.value == "") {
        document.getElementById("names").removeChild(name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `localStorage`: http://jsfiddle.net/y8Uju/8/

Loading:

```
var saved = JSON.parse(localStorage["numbers"] || "[]");
for(var i = 0; i < saved.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById("name").value = saved[i];
    add(false);
}
```

Saving:

```
var saved = JSON.parse(localStorage["numbers"] || "[]");
saved.push(num1.value);
localStorage["numbers"] = JSON.stringify(saved);
```

And define the function of the `addName` button separately, so that you can call it when loading as well.

**Edit:** You have to execute a function when the page is loading to fetch the stored numbers, and add some code to save the entered number when one clicks the Add button.

For storing you can use `localStorage`, but this only accepts Strings. To convert an array (an array containing the entered numbers), you can use JSON.

When loading, you need to add the numbers just like happens when the user fills them in. So you can set the `name` input box value to the saved number for each element in the array, and then simulate a click on the Add button.

So you need an add function that is executed when:

1. User clicks Add button
2. Page is loaded

However, when simulating the click the numbers should not get stored again. You need to distinguish between a real click and a simulated one. You can accomplish this by adding an argument to the add function which represents whether or not to store.

Comment: can you please eleborate on your last comment, A little more explanation would help me better understand

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options available to you:

- Save it client side using cookies (http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html)
- Save it client side using HTML5 local storage (http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/storage.html)
- Save it server-side using Ajax

The Ajax solution involves a server side page (in PHP for example) that reads a request (a POST request for example) and saves it into a database or other. You then query that page in JavaScript using [XmlHTTPRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) or your favorite library.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what the question is, but one problem I see with the code - id's can't be numbers, or start with numbers

```
var nameOfnames = form1.getElementsByClassName("inputNames").length;
//....
newGuy1.setAttribute("id", nameOfnames);
```

That might be slowing you down somewhat. Perhaps set `id` to `'newguy' + nameOfnames`

Answer (score 0):

Jeff, the reason that the page keeps getting erased is because the form submission triggers a page reload. You need to place a listener on the form submit event and then send the data through AJAX. This way the data is POSTed to "text.php" without reloading the page with the form.

You could place the values in a cookie but that is not ideal because you have a fairly limited amount of space to work with (4kb). I also get the feeling that you're trying to hand them off to some server side script so HTML5 local storge wouldnt be a good solution, not to mention that your eliminating over half of the people on the internet from using your site that way.

Since browsers are inconsistent in how they attach event listeners AND how they make AJAX requests. I think that most people would recommend that you use a library like [jQuery](http://jQuery.com/), [dojo](http://dojotoolkit.org), or [prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/) which abstract the process into one function that works in all browsers. (my personal fav is jQuery)